# Use two select options to filter a datatable simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, datatables

I'm looking to use two select option filters on a datatable simultaneously. They currently work well if you select one of them individually, but they don't work in tandem (e.g., if you want to filter by two variables at the same time).

At the moment, once you select a second filter, the first filter becomes void, despite the dropdown still showing the value that had been selected before. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="select">
    <select id="age">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
        <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="select">
    <select id="position">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="accountant">Accountant</option>
        <option value="system architect">System Architect</option>
    </select>
</div>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011-04-25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011-07-25</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Accountant Land</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009-01-12</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012-03-29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008-11-28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
        $('select#age').change(function () { oTable.fnFilter($(this).val()); });
        $('select#position').change(function () { oTable.fnFilter($(this).val()); });
    });
</script>
```

**Issue:**
[image]

Comment: PS. There's a second issue in here that you may have spotted. The select filters search across **all** columns, though they should optimally only select across the relevant column (e.g., Office filter should search only under the office column). Since it's a separate problem, I'll post that separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864133/target-a-select-option-filter-on-a-single-column-on-a-datatable

Comment: The [Datatables column filters](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) would work well for this use case. It targets an individual column and you can combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass column(index) to the fnFilter function

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
     $('select#age').change( function () {  oTable.fnFilter( this.value, 2 );  } );
     $('select#position').change( function () {  oTable.fnFilter( this.value, 1 ); });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="select">
    <select id="age">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
        <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="select">
    <select id="position">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="accountant">Accountant</option>
        <option value="system architect">System Architect</option>
    </select>
</div>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011-04-25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011-07-25</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Accountant Land</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009-01-12</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012-03-29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008-11-28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I've marked your answer as correct. Do you also know how to do so if you're using the `DataTable(); oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();`? As opposed to the `oTable.fnFilter();`