# Target a select option filter on a single column on a datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, datatables

I'm looking to make my select option filter only in targeted columns on a datatable.

At the moment, they target the whole datatable. You can see from this image, that this could throw up an incorrect value if that text happened to exist in a different column.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="select">
    <select id="age">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
        <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="select">
    <select id="position">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="accountant">Accountant</option>
        <option value="system architect">System Architect</option>
    </select>
</div>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011-04-25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011-07-25</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Accountant Land</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009-01-12</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012-03-29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008-11-28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
        $('select#age').change(function () { oTable.fnFilter($(this).val()); });
        $('select#position').change(function () { oTable.fnFilter($(this).val()); });
    });
</script>
```

Possible solutions should take into account that my actual data will be pulled in from python to be part of a flask app.

Possible solutions should take into account that my actual data will be pulled in from python to be part of a flask app.

Comment: PS. There's a related issue that you may have spotted. The filter select options do not work simultaneously. Since that's a separate problem, I've posted that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864121/use-two-select-options-to-filter-a-datatable-simultaneously

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72864459/4746045